# Substring Extraction Around Pattern Match

Tags: awk

I am trying to use the below code to print the 8th character as well as the 18th to 8th characters prior to match.

The code is working for some lines but not for a few others.

For example, In the entry "*ATGGAGGCGAATACATCGAGCTCTGACATACGGA*" after matching "GCTCTG"; it looks something like this "*ATGGAGGCGAATACATCGA**GCTCTG**ACATACGGA*".

With my little understanding, `prefix = substr(rest_of_column, RSTART - 8, 8)` should give me "**TACATCGA**" (8 characters before the match) and `suffix1 = substr(rest_of_column, RSTART - 18, 10)` should give me another 10 characters before the 1st match.

But, as the output file indicates for `prefix = substr(rest_of_column, RSTART - 8, 8)`, it's printing the 1st 8 characters of "*ATGGAGGCGAATACATCGAGCTCTGACATACGGA*" and for `suffix1 = substr(rest_of_column, RSTART - 18, 10)` it's printing characters 19-9 after matching.

*Input File:*

> ws:i:718848     zm:i:7997424    bc:B:S,1,0      bq:i:100        cx:i:12        RG:Z:eb43431c/0--1     XM:Z:   XC:Z:ATGGAGGCGAATACATCGAGCTCTGACATACGGA   XA:Z:XC-XM      qs:i:38     qe:i:2934

*Output File:*

> ws:i:718848     zm:i:7997424    bc:B:S,1,0      bq:i:100        cx:i:12      RG:Z:eb43431c/0--1      XM:Z:ATGGAGGC   XC:Z:ATGGAGGCGA XA:Z:XC-XM      qs:i:38 qe:i:2934

*Expected Output File:*

> ws:i:718848     zm:i:7997424    bc:B:S,1,0      bq:i:100        cx:i:12      RG:Z:eb43431c/0--1      XM:Z:TACATCGA   XC:Z:TGGAGGCGAA XA:Z:XC-XM      qs:i:38 qe:i:2934

Code used:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^XC:Z:/) {
            rest_of_column = substr($i, 6)
                if (match(substr(rest_of_column, length(rest_of_column) - 17), /GCTCTG/)) {
                prefix = substr(rest_of_column, RSTART - 8, 8)
                suffix1 = substr(rest_of_column, RSTART - 18, 10)
                $i = "XC:Z:" suffix1
                 $(NF-4) = $(NF-4) prefix
                                print
                processed = 1
                next
            }
        }
    }
}' OFS="\t"
```

Answer (score 0):

By your elaboration in comments etc, I guess you want something like this:

```
awk '{ xc = xm = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (match($i, /^XC:Z:[ACGT]*([ACGT]{10})([ACGT]{8})GCTCTG/)) {
            xc = i
            prefix = substr($i, RLENGTH-23, 10)
            suffix1 = substr($i, RLENGTH-13, 8)
        }
        else if ($i ~ /^XM:/)
            xm = i
        if (xc && xm) {
            $xc = substr($xc, 1, 5) prefix
            $xm = $xm suffix1
            print
            processed = 1
            next
        }
    }
}' OFS="\t"
```

This takes care to identify which field contains XC: and which field is XM: and only replaces them both when it has identified their proper indices; so this no longer hardcodes that the XM field is `$(NF-4)`.

In very brief, the `match` function gives you `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` values which you clearly already knew roughly how to use; but I have not attempted to debug your attempt in more detail, and instead just tried to implement what you were apparently describing in the addendum. Because we are matching the entire string up to the sequence (I think it's called?) you wanted to find, we use backwards indexing from the end of the match, which is indicated by `RLENGTH`, and subtracting the lengths of the fixed-length substrings we know are there (ten characters for `suffix1`, eight for `prefix`, and six for the static `GCTCTG`).

The parentheses in the regular expression are not useful here, but if you have GNU Awk, you could use the three-parameter extended version of `match` to get the parenthesized expressions extracted into an array conveniently as a side effect of the match, which would simplify the code even further.

Here is an online demo which also hopefully gives you some ideas about how you would attempt to debug this code yourself: https://ideone.com/LLVDe8